# I'm using fs.writeFileSync but the file doesn't appear on the disk and there is no error either

Tags: node.js, fs

A similar question was asked and its solution said to use try, catch method ,I've tried that but the file was still not written and no error was logged to the console.

I've tried changing directory and running powershell as administrator also verified my code from any possible errors from multiple sources but nothing seems to help .

This is the code I've written.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let originalNote = {
   title : 'Some Title',
   body : 'Some Body'
}
//Converting object into JSON string 
let originalNoteString = JSON.stringify(originalNote);

//Writing JSON string to 'notes.json' file
try{
   fs.writeFileSync = ('file.json', originalNoteString);
} catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function call not an assignment

```
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', originalNoteString);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out , but why wasn't there an error while assigning to fs.writeFileSync ?

Comment: @Daksh Why there would be any? It was a perfectly valid assignment.

Comment: I'm kind of naive here ,but  how can pre-defined methods be replaced ?

Comment: @Daksh There is nothing much special about modules shipped with the node itself. You could check code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L550) So unless module author did something to prevent changing module user could redefine this property on his|her will.